# Safari 7 and Chrome 30 on OSX 10.9 not enjoying SSL self signed certificates

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari, ssl-certificate, self-signed

Hello people from the web,

I am experiencing a weird issue with self signed certificates. Since I upgraded to OSX 10.9 (Maverick) I am not able to connect to an HTTPS site protected by a self signed SSL certificate. The only remaining browser on my computer able to do the trick is Firefox (24). Chrome (30) and Safari (7) cannot.

Have you experienced the same issue? Have you found a solution?

On my quest for a solution I found this article:
http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2013-10/0036.html

However it seems to me this is more the webkit common engine causing the issue. Is it possible that Webkit has become more picky with SSL Certificates? In which case how to generate a cutom one that would suit Safari 7 and Chrome 30+?

Thank you for any help you could provide :)

Oscar